# How to get sum of nested array in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate

My Array is like this,

[data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test] => 164.765
                        )

```
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 26.1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 194.564
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 54
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 99.753
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 32.735
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 2715.865
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => 94.595
                    )
            )
```

By using $sum my just getting 0 all time. Is there any way to have sum of this array?

Comment: Show as full aggregation pipeline.

Comment: $fetchquery = [ [  '$project' => [
                                    "_id"=>1,
                                    "data.total_earned_USD" =>1,],], ['$group'=>[ '_id'=>[   'Bucket'=>'$data.bucket_range',], 'test'=>['$push'=>'$data.total_earned_USD'],'total_v'=>['$sum'=>'$data.total_earned_USD'] ] ],]; $final_result = $collection->aggregate($fetchquery);

Comment: can you post the actual documents so we can give you a working code

Comment: {
    "_id" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5715fb9480b5b7342e8b456a")
    },
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "total_earned_USD" : 0.3,
            "bucket_range" : NumberLong(1),
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5715fb9580b5b7342e8b4570")},
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "total_earned_USD" : 0.6,
            "bucket_range" : NumberLong(1),}]}
{
    "_id" : {"id" : ObjectId("5715fbaf80b5b7342e8b45fa")},
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "total_earned_USD" : 0.5,
            "bucket_range" : NumberLong(1),
        }]}

Comment: I resolved the issue there is problem in my collection "data" has type Array after i change "data" to an Object it works fine.
Thanks all for Support.